# Displaying polynomials with linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, polynomials

I am trying to write a code creating and displaying polynomials. My first question is: "Did I use linked list correctly?". Second is: "Why can't I display poynomials?" I want them displayed like: If there are 2 monomials, poynomial should be displayed as; -->(1.0 X 0) -->(1.0 X 3)--E   First one is coefficient second one is the exponent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//this will be the structure named node
struct node
{
    int exp;           //this line represents the exponent/power b for a*x^b
    int coeff;         //this line represents the coefficient a for a*x^b
    struct node *next; //this line represents the pointer which will point to the next node
};
struct node *create_new_nodes(struct node *m);
struct node *insert(struct node *ptr, struct node *k);
void display(char const *tag, struct node *ptr);

struct node *create_new_nodes(struct node *m)
{
    int i;
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b): ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->coeff);
        printf("Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->exp);
        ptr->next = NULL;
    }
    return m;
}

void display(char const *tag, struct node *ptr)
{
    struct node *temp;    
    temp = ptr;
    printf("%s: ", tag);
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("-->(%d X %d)--E", temp->coeff, temp->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL;

    p1 = create_new_nodes(p1);

    p2 = create_new_nodes(p2);

    display("p1", p1);
    display("p2", p2);

    return 0;
}
```

My output for this code:

```
Enter the number of nodes: 2
Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b): 1
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 2
Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b): 2
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 3
Enter the number of nodes: 2
Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b): 3
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 4
Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b): 6
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 5
p1: 
p2:
```

As you can see p1 and p2 are not displayed.

I have to mention that I took help from internet while writing some parts of this code. So, there are parts that I didn't understand. If possible, I would like to be clarified for those too.

```
void display(char const *tag, struct node *ptr)
{
    struct node *temp;
    const char *pad;

    temp = ptr;
    printf("%s: ", tag);
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("-->(%d X %d)--E", temp->coeff, temp->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
        pad = " + ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

In this part of code, I didn't get why I use temp and tag function.

Comment: The `create_new_nodes` function does not actually return anything that links to the create nodes. It just creates some nodes and throws them away.

Comment: @kaylum Doesn't `return m;` do that?

Comment: Well, No.... When you create your list, you set `ptr->next = NULL;`, but never actually set where the `next` pointer points later (no links means no list...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, I see. How can I fix it?

Comment: Here is a [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) that uses a separate struct to hold the `head` and `tail` pointers in addition to the node pointer holding the payload (`int` here) and the `next` pointer. Using both a `head` and `tail` pointer allows O(1) in-order insertion into the list without having to iterate to the last node. It will show you basic list operations. You can simply change `int` to `double`, etc.. There are literally hundreds of example on this site too. You can search on StackOverflow with `"[c] linked-list"`

Comment: Also, you cannot use any input function correctly (especially `scanf()`) unless you **check the return**. Save yourself lots of grief. Instead of `scanf("%d", &n);` it's `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }` That will minimally catch a *matching-failure* and prevent invoking *Undefined Behavior* (bad).

Comment: Hi marta. I notice that you have asked multiple questions on very closely related topics, concerning your polynomial project. While that is appreciated (as opposed to making one huge post covering several questios), it is a little disappointing to see questions on which others and I have provided feedback being deleted amd replaced by different cloesely related questions. Please keep the questions on which people have spent effort, because otherwise you risk that many users like me lose confidence in the effect of trying to help you. If you asked focused questions on parts, keep them, please.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm so sorry about that. Everytime something went wrong so I thought it would be better if I would just delete them. Once it was closed because it wasn't clear and even though I tried to edit and make it better, I still couldn't open it. And same problem happened several times. I didn't notice that I deleted any question with an answer. If this happened, I apologize to you and the others if there is someone else. I will keep it in mind and from now on try to ask my questions better so I won't need to delete them. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get you sorted out. Rather than a full general linked-list implementation, you simply need the create, display, and delete functions. Since your lists are just links of structs with `exp` and `coeff`, you can simply build a new list each time you call your create function. You do NOT need to provide a parameter to your create function, just declare your list pointer local to the function and then return a pointer to the first node in the allocated list when done.

As noted in the comment, you are headed for a lot of grief unless you ***check the return*** for every input function used (and not mentioned, but equally important, check the return of EVERY allocation)

You were not terribly far off where you were headed with your create function, you just never linked the nodes together in your list. You do want to initialize the `next` pointer `NULL` following allocation, but you also have to set any existing end node in your list `next` pointer to point to the new node. That is how you create the "link" in the "linked-list".

Let's take your create function, (I've renamed it `create_poly_list()`) and essentially you can declare both `head` and `tail` list pointers local to the function (the `tail` pointer is temporary used to build the list) and then return `head` when done for assignment back in the caller (`main()` here). So all you really needed would be to declare your list pointers, and then add each node in-order, e.g.

```
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;             /* temporary list pointers */
    ...
        if (head == NULL)           /* add first node */
            head = tail = ptr;
        else {
            tail->next = ptr;       /* set last node ->next to new node */
            tail = ptr;             /* update tail to new node */
        }
    ...
    return head;                    /* return pointer to start of list */
```

Then in `main()` you would simply call `create_poly_list()` for each polynomial, e.g.

```
    p1 = create_poly_list();
    p2 = create_poly_list();
```

Now let's tidy it up so you validate each input and allocation, returning `NULL` on either input or allocation failure (and remembering to `free()` all memory if memory was allocated prior to the failure to prevent a memory leak), e.g.

```
struct node *create_poly_list (void)                    /* no parameter required */
{
    int i, n;
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;             /* temporary list pointers */
    
    fputs ("\nEnter the number of nodes: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return NULL;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct node *ptr = malloc (sizeof *ptr);
        if (!ptr) {                                     /* validate EVERY allocation */
            while (head) {                              /* if nodes in list */
                struct node *victim = head;             /* free all nodes (or leak) */
                head = head->next;
                free (victim);
            }
            return NULL;                                /* now return NULL on error */
        }
        ptr->next = NULL;                               /* initialize next ptr NULL */
        
        fputs ("\nEnter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%d", &ptr->coeff) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            /* you would likewise need to free prior nodes here */
            return NULL;
        }
        
        fputs ("Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): ", stdout);
        if (scanf("%d", &ptr->exp) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            /* you would likewise need to free prior nodes here */
            return NULL;
        }
        
        if (head == NULL)           /* add first node */
            head = tail = ptr;
        else {
            tail->next = ptr;       /* set last node ->next to new node */
            tail = ptr;             /* update tail to new node */
        }
    }
    
    return head;                    /* return pointer to start of list */
}
```

Your `display()` function was good, but you should check if `ptr` is `NULL` (e.g. list empty) to inform the user of the list state in case an attempt is made to display an empty list, e.g.

```
void display (char const *tag, struct node *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) {                     /* validate list not NULL */
        puts ("(list-empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    struct node *temp = ptr;
    
    printf("%s: ", tag);
    
    while (temp) {
        printf("-->(%d X %d)--E", temp->coeff, temp->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Here you need to free the memory of each list when you are done with it. (yes, the memory will be freed on program exit, but presumably you won't always be writing simple programs that create all lists in `main()`). Build good memory management habits early. A simple delete list function is all you need, e.g.

```
void del_list (struct node *list)
{
    while (list) {
        struct node *victim = list;
        list = list->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int exp;
    int coeff;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *create_poly_list (void)                    /* no parameter required */
{
    int i, n;
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;             /* temporary list pointers */
    
    fputs ("\nEnter the number of nodes: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return NULL;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct node *ptr = malloc (sizeof *ptr);
        if (!ptr) {                                     /* validate EVERY allocation */
            while (head) {                              /* if nodes in list */
                struct node *victim = head;             /* free all nodes (or leak) */
                head = head->next;
                free (victim);
            }
            return NULL;                                /* now return NULL on error */
        }
        ptr->next = NULL;                               /* initialize next ptr NULL */
        
        fputs ("\nEnter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%d", &ptr->coeff) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            /* you would likewise need to free prior nodes here */
            return NULL;
        }
        
        fputs ("Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): ", stdout);
        if (scanf("%d", &ptr->exp) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            /* you would likewise need to free prior nodes here */
            return NULL;
        }
        
        if (head == NULL)           /* add first node */
            head = tail = ptr;
        else {
            tail->next = ptr;       /* set last node ->next to new node */
            tail = ptr;             /* update tail to new node */
        }
    }
    
    return head;                    /* return pointer to start of list */
}

void display (char const *tag, struct node *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) {                     /* validate list not NULL */
        puts ("(list-empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    struct node *temp = ptr;
    
    printf("%s: ", tag);
    
    while (temp) {
        printf("-->(%d X %d)--E", temp->coeff, temp->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    
    putchar('\n');
}

void del_list (struct node *list)
{
    while (list) {
        struct node *victim = list;
        list = list->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL;

    p1 = create_poly_list();
    p2 = create_poly_list();
    
    putchar ('\n');
    display("p1", p1);
    display("p2", p2);
    
    del_list (p1);
    del_list (p2);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** why you have included `string.h` is a bit bewildering...)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/poly_list

Enter the number of nodes: 2

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 2
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 6

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 3
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 7

Enter the number of nodes: 3

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 1
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 3

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 3
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 5

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 5
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 7

p1: -->(2 X 6)--E-->(3 X 7)--E
p2: -->(1 X 3)--E-->(3 X 5)--E-->(5 X 7)--E
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/poly_list
==23402== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23402== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23402== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23402== Command: ./bin/poly_list
==23402==

Enter the number of nodes: 2

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 2
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 6

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 3
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 7

Enter the number of nodes: 3

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 1
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 3

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 3
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 5

Enter the coefficient (a for a*x^b)   : 5
Enter the exponent/power (b for a*x^b): 7

p1: -->(2 X 6)--E-->(3 X 7)--E
p2: -->(1 X 3)--E-->(3 X 5)--E-->(5 X 7)--E
==23402==
==23402== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23402==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23402==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 2,128 bytes allocated
==23402==
==23402== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23402==
==23402== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23402== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer that was very explanatory! I just have one question that I didn't understand in code is `struct node *temp = ptr;` function. Why do we use this one?

Comment: Good question, that is not critical since `ptr` is passed as a parameter and will be a local variable to `display()`. Generally, you want to avoid iterating with your list pointer. So I generally declare a temporary pointer to iterate with. (in fact I believe `temp` came from your original code). So I left it. In functions like `del_list()` where there will be no list left when the function returns -- there you can iterate with the actual pointer without ever needing a temporary pointer. So in `display()` I suspect the `temp` was just used for iteration purposes out of habit...

Comment: Yes, actually, it was in my original code. But as I mentioned in my question I didn't know how to display my polynomials so, I took that part from the internet and didn't understand why was that necessary. Now I see the reason, thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome, Good luck with your coding! Drop a comment if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but in the function

```
struct node *create_new_nodes(struct node *m)
```

it looks like both the return type and the parameter are pointers. So really, you are returning

```
struct node **m
```

Not sure if that's what's wrong, but if it is, the same issue might appear when you do

```
printf("-->(%d X %d)--E", temp->coeff, temp->exp);
```

when `temp` is `ptr` which is `struct node*`. So really you are saying `(**node).coeff`. But this is just my tired observation, if it works just ignore me.